# How to make bootstrap card height responsive

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap card like this:

```
<div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
          This is some text within a card body.
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the height responsive. For example: for larger screen `h-70`, for medium devices `h-50` like this how can I do that.

Comment: I don't understand properly, how do you make the **height** responsive?? Can you show some images of what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use media queries in css like

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { height:10% }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { height:25% }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) { height:50% }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) { height:70% }
```

You can also change the width according to screen size as needed like a window with `maximum width 500px` need to have a `height of 20%` so you can write like this

```
@media (max-width: 500px) { height:20% }
```